# change connection string in crystal report at run time and take record according to new connection

Tags: .net

I have change connection string at run time but it not picking the record from new 
connection string. Code is:

```
private void Report_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (ConnectionInfo item in Tests1.DataSourceConnections)
            {
                item.SetConnection(@".\sqlexpress", @"C:\DBFile\fff2011.mdf", true);
            }
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Tests1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used ODBC as the datasource in the report to do this. That way you don't have to change the report or anything in code when going between live and test.